# Calculating A Determinant From A 2x3 Array Matrix

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, boolean

So I have written the code below as a program to solve a 2-D linear system of equations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
  int eq[2][3];

  int D, Dx, Dy;

  int sol[2];

  printf("Enter cofficients of first equation: ");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &eq[0][0], &eq[0][1], &eq[0][2]); 

  printf("Enter cofficients of second equation: ");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &eq[1][0], &eq[1][1], &eq[1][2]);

  D = eq[0][0]*eq[1][1] - eq[1][0]*eq[0][1];
  Dx = eq[0][2]*eq[1][1] - eq[1][2]*eq[0][1];
  Dy = eq[0][0]*eq[1][2] - eq[1][0]*eq[0][2];

  if(D != 0){
    sol[0] = Dx/D;   // x solution
    sol[1] = Dy/D;   // y solution

    printf("x = %d, y = %d \n", sol[0], sol[1]);
  }
  else{
    printf("No unique solutions exist. \n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have now been tasked with converting this into a function using the prototype:

```
 bool determinantFunction(int e[][3], int s[]);
```

My problem is that I don't know where to start. I have read up on using booleans in C as much as I can but I don't understand how or why I would implement that into making a determinant function.

Comment: I believe we are to use the boolean return value to determine if a solution was actually computed. So yeah, it should return true for a non-zero determinant and false for a zero determinant.

Comment: The "Determinant" is calculated from a 2x2 (not 2x3) matrix.  The solution is calculated from the 2x3 Matrix.

Answer (score 1):

So, just putting your existing code in such a function (and I'm not saying your code is right or wrong), you get something like:

```
bool determinantFunction(int e[][3], int s[])
{
    int D, Dx, Dy;

    // calculate determinant
    D  = e[0][0]*e[1][1] - e[1][0]*e[0][1];
    Dx = e[0][2]*e[1][1] - e[1][2]*e[0][1];
    Dy = e[0][0]*e[1][2] - e[1][0]*e[0][2];

    // if non-singular ...
    if (D != 0)
    {
        // success
        s[0] = Dx/D;   // return x solution
        s[1] = Dy/D;   // return y solution
        return true;
    }

    // no solution
    return false;
}
```

Then your `main` becomes something like this (not tested):

```
int main( )
{
    int eq[2][3];
    int sol[2];

    printf("Enter cofficients of first equation: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &eq[0][0], &eq[0][1], &eq[0][2]); 

    printf("Enter cofficients of second equation: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &eq[1][0], &eq[1][1], &eq[1][2]);

    if (determinantFunction(eq, sol))
    {
        printf("x = %d, y = %d \n", sol[0], sol[1]);
    }
    else{
        printf("No unique solutions exist. \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For your example : 4x - 3y = -14 and 3x - 5y = -5, which is the same as:

4x - 3y + 14 = 0
3x - 5y +  5 = 0

You'd get:

[image: result]

Ok, last update - hardcoded coefficients:

```
int eq[2][3] = {{4, -3, 14}, {3, -5, 5}};
int sol[2];
if (determinantFunction(eq, sol))
{
    printf("x = %d, y = %d \n", sol[0], sol[1]);
}
else{
    printf("No unique solutions exist. \n");
}
```

Comment: Say, for instance, I wanted to solve this system of equations:
      (4x - 3y = -14)

      (3x - 5y = -5)

How would I translate that into the function call?

Comment: If I wanted to hardcode that system of equations in, I would need to make a function call in main, right? How exactly would I go about that?

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you so much. I think I was over thinking how _bool_ could be implemented into my previous code, this certainly makes more sense now. Thanks @Roger!

Comment: @Roger Rowland Is `s[0] = Dx/D;` potentially a division with a loss due to truncation?

Comment: @chux yes, it's all integer arithmetic, which is why I said "I'm not saying your code is right or wrong" - it works fine for the example equations but it will be inaccurate for others. That's for the OP to fix - easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way such a function could work is to return `true` if there was a unique solution and `false` otherwise. If the solution was indeed found, it would be stored in the array passed as second argument.

Basically, you would just move your existing code into a function. Your `sol` array will be passed to you as the first argument.

```
int main()
{
    int eq[2][3];
    // ...
    int sol[2];
    if (determinantFunction(eq, sol)) {
        printf("%d %d\n", sol[0], sol[1]);
    } else {
        printf("No unique solutions exist.\n");
    }
}
```